# Config Collection View Cell

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Hi I have a ViewController that has a CollectionView inside. and I have trouble to configure a custom view cell of the collection view.

Here is my ViewController

```
import UIKit
class achievmentViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate , UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
    @IBOutlet weak var progressBar: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet weak var aCollectionView: UICollectionView!     
    override func viewDidLoad() {        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        aCollectionView.delegate = self
        aCollectionView.dataSource = self
        aCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        aCollectionView.registerClass(achievmentViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "achievmentCell")
        let w = self.view.frame.width-40
        let h = self.view.frame.height-72
        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: h*(5/100), left: w*(3.1/100), bottom: h*(5/100), right:  w*(3.1/100))
         layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: w*(27/100), height: h*(30/100))
        aCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 72, width: w, height: h), collectionViewLayout: layout)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell:achievmentViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("achievmentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! achievmentViewCell

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        cell.setTextForLabel("test")
        cell.Label?.text = "test"
        print(cell.Label?.text)

       // cell.setImageForImageView(UIImage(named: "badge")!)
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "badge")!
        return cell
    }



    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }

}
```

And here is my collectionViewCell Class:

```
import UIKit
class achievmentViewCell: UICollectionViewCell{
    @IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
}
```

And when I run them all i got is a view cell that nothing but it background color. Once again help please this is for my final. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error for you. So in your code when you call the collectionView you are calling a generic collectionView instead of the collectionView that you linked inside your achievmentViewController.

```
    let cell:achievmentViewCell = acollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("achievmentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! achievmentViewCell
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 things that might be the problem here.

First, and problably this is the problem, classes names must be written in CamelCase, starting with **uppercase**. So make sure you change all references of `achievmentViewCell` to `AchievmentViewCell` (including file name). So it will look like this:

```
let cell:AchievmentViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("achievmentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AchievmentViewCell
```

Second, make sure you added the `achievmentCell` cell identifier on storyboard.

[image]

Comment: Actually it was some problem in the storyboard that It allow the collection view to have different Controller class: CollectionView and UICollectionView. And I chose the wrong one. Thank any way